# Why does Docker "ancestry" API command not work?

Tags: api, registry, docker

The Docker Registry API Documentation ([here](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/registry_api/#get-image-ancestry)) states that you can do:
`https://index.docker.io/v1/images/088b4505aa3adc3d35e79c031fa126b403200f02f51920fbd9b7c503e87c7a2c/ancestry`

However this (with several image ids I have tried) only yields a 404. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the incorrect domain. Note from the documentation example:

```
GET /v1/images/088b4505aa3adc3d35e79c031fa126b403200f02f51920fbd9b7c503e87c7a2c/ancestry HTTP/1.1
    Host: registry-1.docker.io
    Accept: application/json
    Content-Type: application/json
    Cookie: (Cookie provided by the Registry)
```

You should be using registry-1.docker.io, not index.docker.io. So your url should be:

```
https://registry-1.docker.io/v1/images/088b4505aa3adc3d35e79c031fa126b403200f02f51920fbd9b7c503e87c7a2c/ancestry
```

When I run this I no longer get a 404 but instead get an authorization error. This is because you need to auth against index.docker.io and then run your api against registry-1.docker.io.

It's not well documented - you may find this discussion helpful:

https://forums.docker.com/t/registry-hub-api-is-buggy/732

from the discussion:

> registry-1.docker.io is the docker-registry used for storing images,
>   this API is public, but requires authorization.
>
> index.docker.io is the "index" now called RegistryHub, this tags
>   endpoint is not public, and might change at any time. I would not use
>   this one, since it is for internal use only, and may change without
>   warning.